# IIS 8.0 URL Rewrite Module not working for Orchard CMS URL Redirect

Tags: iis, orchardcms, iis-8

I have hosted an Orchard site locally on my machine on IIS 8.0 using SQL LocalDb. 
I have also installed and integrated the URL Rewrite module in IIS.
I have modified the web.config in the Orchard.Web project for redirecting as

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect services to expertise" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/services/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/expertise/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

So, what I intend to do is redirect from `"http://localhost:70/Orchard/services/content-management" to "http://localhost:70/Orchard/expertise/content-management".`
But this is not working as intended and there is no redirection. It opens up the same old "../services/.." URL.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your rule. The url does not have a leading slash. Try change the rule to:

```
<rule name="Redirect services to expertise" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^services/(.*)" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="expertise/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This will redirect any url starting with services/... to expertise/...

Comment: But the pattern I specified matches perfectly. I tested it in IIS using the URL Rewrite Module "Test Pattern". The one you specified does not match.

Comment: Have you tried the above rule? It might not be your only problem, but the url should not have a leading forward slash. The example in the "Test Pattern" tool is "catalog/products/sale" - no leading forward slash. If you test my rule against "services/some-page" it does match.